# Number of bytes in UiImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bitmap

I have a confusion regarding getting number of bytes in UIImage

To get number of bytes we use NSdata byts,

I have have an image of size 128X160 size, and NSData bytes tell it have 400669 bytes

But as per calculation in 3 channel image of  8 bit color i.e 24bit per pixel the number of bytes should be 3X128X160 = 61440 byts

Please help and let me know why NSData tell different in number of bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The underlying data of a `UIImage` can vary, so for the same "image" one can have varying sizes of data. One thing you can do is use `UIImagePNGRepresentation` or `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to get the equivalent `NSData` constructs for either, then check the size of that.

Comment: Dear i know UIImagePNGRepresentation can give Size, but i want to know getting size by Manual calculation like i did in question is wrong?